Why is stdout not a tty?
Why is stdout not a tty, even though stderr is? Please let me know if you need more context, added this line to pass stackoverflow's validation.
$ php -r 'var_dump(exec("test -t 1 && echo y"));'
string(0) ""
$ php -r 'var_dump(system("test -t 1 && echo y"));'
string(0) ""
$ php -r 'var_dump(passthru("test -t 1 && echo y"));'
NULL
$ php -r 'var_dump(exec("test -t 2 && echo y"));'
string(1) "y"
$ php -r 'var_dump(system("test -t 2 && echo y"));'
y
string(1) "y"
$ php -r 'var_dump(passthru("test -t 2 && echo y"));'
y
NULL
$ php -v
PHP 8.2.20 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2024 02:23:40) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.20, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
$ uname -rsm
FreeBSD 13.3-RELEASE-p1 amd64


I think its because results of stdout can be (and often are) redirected to files and pipelines, and when redirected, then no longer need a terminal. However, stderr is often left directly connected to the terminal (tty) even when it is redirected.

All of these PHP functions redirect stdout but not stderr. Use proc_open() if you want to catch both stdout and stderr.

What about shell_exec() ? php -r 'var_dump(shell_exec("ls not_a_valid_path 2>&1")); outputs: string(84) "ls: impossible d'accéder à 'not_a_valid_path': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce nom "

All these functions redirect their stdout so that it can be processed in various ways.
exec() returns the last line of its output, and if a second argument is given it stores an array of all the lines in that variable. It does both of these by redirecting stdout to a pipe.
system() and passthru() use a pipe to copy the output to PHP's output buffer. Even when PHP's output is going to the terminal, it uses an output buffer for the benefit of the ob_XXX() functions. Also, system() returns the last line of output, which requires capturing the output through a pipe.
stderr is not redirected by default.
